# Understanding working of multiple gunicorn process

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, acid

I have no knowledge of what I'm trying to understand, surfing the internet brought me here and now I need this in my code.

I use django-rest-framework, gunicorn, and Nginx.

Suppose I have 3 workers process of gunicorn setup.

and I have a very simple view that reads a value from the database, performs a different task that takes around 1 second, increments the value by 1, and saves it back to the database.

```
class CreateView():
    value = MyModel.objects.get(id=1).integerValueField
    otherTask() #takes around 1 second (assume)
    updatedValue = value + 1
    MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(integerValueField=updatedValue)
    return
```

Will this always work?

what if a different worker process of gunicorn is handling the request of concurrent users? If the database is updated (integerValueField field) by a different process **in between** reading the value and updating the value by some other worker process? Is this locked somehow to maintain integrity?

if I can get valid links to read more about the topic, will work well for me.

Comment: You'll want to use `select_for_update` to lock the row for the duration of the view to processes it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Comment: I will do this inside atomic transaction by including the above piece of code in `with transaction.atomic()`.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to lock the rows - depends on your use case. You can leverage [Django's `F()` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f-1) to avoid race conditions in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on The Pjot‘s comment - no, the code you provided won't work reliably if you execute it with multiple Gunicorn workers. What happens here is called a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and isn't actually anything that is specific to Django - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850336/database-race-conditions) is a discussion of exactly this in a more general database setting.

Now, what would happen in your specific case if multiple Gunicorn workers access the same object ([or a single worker with multiple threads](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#design)) looks roughly like this if we assume that `MyModel.objects.get(id=1).integerValueField` is `100` at the beginning:

1. worker 1 executes `value = MyModel.objects.get(id=1).integerValueField`, which will [hit the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets) and retrieve the object with primary key `1` and store it in memory. `value` will be set to the value of `integerValueField`, which is `100`in our example
2. worker 1 executes `otherTask()`
3. worker 2 executes `value = MyModel.objects.get(id=1).integerValueField` and just as worker 1 it will store the current value of `integerValueField` in the database in `value`. `value`, again, will be `100` as the value hasn't yet changed in the database
4. worker 2 executes `otherTask()`
5. worker 1 will now execute `updatedValue = value + 1`, which sets `updatedValue` to `101` and then execute `MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(integerValueField=updatedValue)` to save it to the database
6. worker 2 will now execute `updatedValue = value + 1` as well - but `value` will be also `101` instead of `102`, as the local copy of the database value is used. No additional database access happens here. After that it will execute `MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(integerValueField=updatedValue)` as well, which will update the database, but won't change the value - it still will be `101`

What `select_for_update` does is it locks the database row so it cannot be accessed by any other worker at the same time (this is a concept that is called [mutual exclusive access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and is often implemented through [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science))). This will solve your issue of lost updates. However, what you should consider here is that you will block all access to this row while the `otherTask()` is running (which is apparently a substantial time) and this can easily lead to long delays for your clients and worse.
I'd really consider if there isn't a better way to solve this. If not I'd at least look into [multi-threaded Gunicorn workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html?highlight=worker#how-many-threads) - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425620/gunicorn-workers-and-threads) is a good discussion.

Comment: "If not I'd at least look into multi-threaded Gunicorn workers - here is a good discussion." What's the relevance?

Comment: If the worker is blocked by a long-running task like `otherTask()` additional threads might help to mitigate the delays caused by said task as additional requests can be processed by this worker in separate threads. At least if we assume that the task isn't compute-bound.